# scala: best wat to save csv coming from kafka to parquet format?

Tags: scala, schema, parquet

I'm new to scala/java, so please bear with me.
I have a spark streaming and scala program that receives a csv file coming from kafka. I understand that what I get right now is a ReceiverInputDStream with plain lines (no schema yet).
I need to save the data I receive in parquet format in HDFS. I guess I could simply save the lines as they come in a parquet file (can I?).
But also I understand it's better to give some schema (columns and types) to the plain lines so parquet can convert the data to columnar format and achieve a better compression rate. Am I right?
So the question is, how do I convert my ReceiverInputDStream to something with a schema (column1 type1,... columnN typeN)? What object type is needed?
ANd then how do I save this new object to parquet?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Spark, you can do

```
spark.read.parquet(parquetPath).write.csv(newcsvPath)
```

Or you can use the same thing but Spark Streaming as a Kafka client

Comment: Hi elarib Thank you for your answer, but what I need is to write to parquet, and need to know if I must give a schema to the ReceiverInputDStream I have.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself, I was able to give format to the RDD and at the same time convert it to a dataframe with the following code

```
val viajesDF = splitRdd.map { case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12, s13, s14, s15, s16, s17, s18) =>
yellowSchema(s0, s1, s2, s3.toInt, s4.toDouble, s5.toFloat, s6.toFloat, s7.toString, s8.toString,
s9.toFloat, s10.toFloat, s11, s12.toDouble, s13.toDouble,
s14.toDouble, s15.toDouble, s16.toDouble, s17.toDouble, s18.toDouble)
}.toDF()
```

The schema is defined as a case class as follows in a different scala object

```
case class  yellowSchema (
                       vendor_id: String,
                       tpep_pickup_datetime: String,
                       tpep_dropoff_datetime: String,
                       passenger_count:  Long,
                       trip_distance: Double,
                       pickup_longitude: Float,
                       pickup_latitude: Float,
                       rate_code_id:  String,
                       store_and_fwd_flag:  String,
                       dropoff_longitude: Float,
                       dropoff_latitude: Float,
                       payment_type:  String,
                       fare_amount: Double,
                       extra: Double,
                       mta_tax: Double,
                       tip_amount: Double,
                       tolls_amount: Double,
                       improvement_surcharge: Double,
                       total_amount: Double
                     )
```

I finally write the DF to parquet this way:

```
viajesDateDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(parquetDest)
```